# Xcode - sqlite database not displaying date (BLANK)

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I have the below code that should populate the TableViewController with information from my sqlite file, it lets me add fine, and i can view  the file and the information is there, but I'm getting nothing in the table, just a blank table screen.

```
-(NSMutableArray *) stockList
{

NSString *filePath = [self getWritableDBPath];

if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    const char *sql = "Select Description, Quantity from StockTable";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with query: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    else
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            Stock * stock = [[Stock alloc] init];

            const char *desc = sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0);
            if (desc)
            {
                stock.desc = @(desc);
            }

            const char *qty = sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 1);
            if (qty)
            {
                stock.qty = @(qty);
            }
            //stock.desc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 1)];
            //stock.qty = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)];

            [thestock addObject:stock];
            stock = nil;
        }

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(db);
return thestock;
}
```

i have the below connection strings: (reason being it causes a LINK error and states that MyDB is a duplicate in both views)

TableView:

> ```
> NSString * MyDB2=@"StockDatabase.db";
> ```

AddingView:

> ```
> NSString * MyDB=@"StockDatabase.db";
> ```

in the console window on the bottom pane the first result displays for the description and quantity from the table, although quantity is shown as 0x1 and the stockArray shows as nil. not sure if this will help you.

it looks like quantity is remaining as nil, so its something to do with:

```
            const char *qty = sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 1);
            if (qty)
            {
                stock.qty = @(qty);
            }
```

Comment: Better to use FMDB for everything SQLite, instead of writing repeated code.

Comment: ill have a look into that, cheers for the input

Comment: Once you have figured out how to use FMDB you will thank it's author :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly one issue with the above code was that the SELECT statement needed a star in to select all fields in the table, don't know why you have to do this but it solved one issue.

Secondly I reverted back the the commented out code above where it selects the information as the 2 fields i am grabbing from the table are both not null's so the fields could never be null.

Finally I added an NSObject to represent Stock which is as simple as this: (the header just contains the synthesise declarations)

```
@interface Stock : NSObject{
NSString *desc;
NSString *qty;
}

@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *qr;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *qty;
```

this information is then passed into an NSMulableArray which is called in the main part of the code:

```
@interface StockList : UITableViewController{
NSMutableArray *thestock;
sqlite3 * db;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *thestock;

-(NSMutableArray *) stockList;
```

below is the amended main part of the code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) stockList{
thestock = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StockControl.db"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }


    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM  StockTable";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{

        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            Stock * stock = [[Stock alloc] init];
            stock.desc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
            stock.qty = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
            [thestock addObject:stock];
            stock=nil;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return thestock;
}
}
```

not sure if its the best way to do this but it works :) any improvements suggested would be great...